# A The way to get the exact location for a device without a GPS unit (i.e. laptop) and based on the wifi connection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, location, navigator

I am currently using:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => console.log({position});
```

this gives you a very wide guesstimate to your current location and cannot suffice for the application I'm builsing that would require a precise location of a max radius of 50 meters.
Navigator is half deprecated and just sits there with very basic usage, I tried passing certain variables I've found for more precision, yet either some were deprecated or weren't producing any changes in precision of location.

We all know for a fact that (in most cases) your maps.google.com will have your pinpointed location on the map (blue dot) with ultra precision, and not only google applications, but other applications that have deep usage of your location (say uber for example) yet for some reason, I can't get that through `window.navigator`.

It's factual that some large tech companies like [Google and Apple](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-bard-can-now-deliver-results-based-on-your-precise-location-if-you-want/) for instance have our exact location, on regular chrome websites (reminder; not on a device with a GPS), for instance - `maps.google.com`, you'll have your location on the map with ultra precision (as a blue dot.

so this:

```
if ('connection' in navigator) {
  const networkInfo = navigator.connection;
  if (networkInfo.type === 'wifi') {
    const ssid = networkInfo.ssid;
    console.log('SSID:', ssid);
  }else{console.log('no');
}
```

will not work on any wifi I tried this on (approx 8)

**So my question is: how do I get user BSSID connection like all large tech companies?**

Comment: Anything concerning `navigator.*` (and other browser-only APIs) is not related to V8. I'll adjust tags.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, Google Maps uses the exact same `navigator.geolocation` as you.

Check it out:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(f=>{Ntg(this,f,b,{noZoom:c,callback:d})},f=>{Otg(this,f,d,e)},{enableHighAccuracy:!0,timeout:1E4,maximumAge:3E5})
```

[Source](https://www.google.com/maps/_/js/k=maps.m.en.3TObXB33t3Y.2019.O/ck=maps.m.0yU5u5N_mi0.L.W.O/m=pwd,bpw,duc,fp,pbw,rsw,rw,zm,lsw,mm,amw,cmw,mld,vm,zsv,ks,wm,pas,omm,h,aew,rl,cls,pnt,svc,hc,omw,pm,asm,at,vim,sem,sl,rvc,rvm,idm,ml,am,ppa,lss/am=BoIVAAg/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oFr1ZwFWZV3Y4bJ7S2VTiLdev8EXw/ed=1/exm=sc2,per,mo,lp,ti,ds,stx,dwi,enr,bom,b,vwr,vd,a,nrw,owc,ob2,sp,en,smi,sc,vlg,log,smr,as,wrc,obp) (It's minifed, so you'll have to search for `geolocation.getCurrentPosition`).

There is an additional parameter `enableHighAccuracy` you can turn on as part of the third `options` argument to `getCurrentPosition`, which may help, but based on the docs, it sounds like that really only matters on devices with a GPS. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition). Indeed, getting the location of my PC returned the same result with or without it, but ymmv.

I verified the resulting location google maps gave me was the exact same location that my own website gave me, to the ten-millionth of a degree. Now to be fair, that was still off by about 500m or so, but then again, your network location is only an estimate anyway. Without a GPS, you can't reliably determine precise location.

<sup>and while wifi may give decent-ish results, try a cellular network and your location can be on the other side of the country</sup>

---

Any additional accuracy Google Maps manages to determine is likely due to other information you voluntarily provide. For instance, if you've set your home address in Google Maps and Google detects you're accessing from your home IP address, it can <sup><sub>probably</sub></sup> put two and two together and pinpoint you to your home address. I don't know their exact implementation, but I can tell you one thing: they are not getting that precise location just from `navigator.geolocation` or any other built-in library.

Comment: Lovely answer for elaboration and interest, yet still doesn't answer the question: "how do I get user BSSID connection like all large tech companies?"